# Flutter theme is not changed on Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, windows-10, desktop-application

I am new to Flutter and decided to follow a tutorial on making a spotify clone using Flutter. He specifies a custom dark theme, and when he runst the code it is indeed a dark theme, but when I run it it is still white. I initially thought I made a type somewhere so I copied his code, but it did not change anything.

I get this result
[image: The result I get]

This is the result I want to get
[image: The expected result]

My main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Spotify());
}

class Spotify extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Spotify UI',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.black),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF121212),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF121212),
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
        accentColor: const Color(0xFF1DB954),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData().copyWith(color: Colors.black),
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline2: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 32.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          headline4: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            letterSpacing: 2.0,
          ),
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
          ),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: Shell(),
    );
  }
}

class Shell extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: 280.0,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                // PlaylistScreen
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 84.0,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set  `backgroundColor: Colors.black,` in `Scaffold()`